# recursively collect paths of a given root dir, when tens of millions files expected

Tags: java, python

I need to create a list/lists of file paths under a given root directory, 
when I expect the number of files under this directory to be tens of millions.

What would be a good and efficient way to do this?

I currently run a python script which runs os.walk multithreaded.

Any better way to achieve what I need?

should be noted that the direcotry is a nfs mounted drive.

Comment: on Linux or UNIX you have `find` command that could be used for that purpose. Simply invoke: `find your_root_directory`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) is generator function:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.walk(".")
<generator object walk at 0x100f32f00>
```

what makes it a good candidate in your case.

Multithreaded solution probably doesn't produce performance benefits, so I would suggest  converting it to some [better concurrent python library](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Concurrency) (like builtin [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)).

Split-job algorithm which spawns processes is probably the most critical part of the system and should be tuned carefully.

Since directory is on a remote system, for sure it will be faster to run script on the remote system, and making remote app sound also reasonable.

Like @javadeveloper suggested, you could also test solution: calling OS list directory function (ls/find/dir) + scripting it in shell language (bash, DOS) or redirect output to file/stream + parsing it in scripting language (like python).